# Is there a way to still get discontinued programs?

Tags: download

Winamp was officially discontinued today. It is no longer available for download, so I am trying to find a copy. It’s not so bad at right now because it’s still fresh, but what if I didn’t notice its discontinuation until later on?

Is there a way to get this or other programs that have been discontinued by the developers?

Comment: By the way, some [mysterious party is interested in purchasing Winamp and Shoutcast](http://www.tomshardware.com/news/winamp-aol-microsoft-shoutcast-mp3,25499.html). (I for one switched to XMPlay back in 2003—though I’ve recently started using a stripped-version of Winamp recently because XMPlay—[*still*](http://www.un4seen.com/forum/?topic=2677.msg98494#msg98494)—doesn’t support [PaceMaker](http://www.winamp.com/plugin/pacemaker/12689), and I can’t stand anything at 1x.)

Comment: @DavidPostill This is not asking for a recommended website where I can get discontinued programs, but for a *way* to get discontinued programs. This close reason does not apply. (Keep in mind that it did get closed for this reason long ago in the past, but was later reopened.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the current version of many popular programs at [SoftPedia](http://softpedia.com) and [Download.com](http://download.cnet.com/). You can get not only the current version, but even *past* versions of many programs at [FileHippo](http://filehippo.com/).

Not surprisingly, Winamp is available [on](http://filehippo.com/download_winamp/) [all](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Multimedia/Audio/Audio-Players/Winamp-5.shtml) [three](http://download.cnet.com/Winamp/3000-2141_4-10251792.html).

Comment: (Wow; I hadn’t heard that Winamp was being discontinued. I remember when the very first version came of it and ICQ came out. I still have a copy on the very first CD I ever burned. We really had fun with those on the University LAN and the brand-spanking-new Internet. Ah, good times.)